# update executed on every row of the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS scores;

CREATE TABLE scores
  (
     id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     nom   VARCHAR(10),
     score INTEGER,
     rang  INTEGER
  );

INSERT INTO scores
VALUES      (1,'a',91,11),
            (2,'b',92,12),
            (3,'c',93,13),
            (4,'d',94,14);

UPDATE scores
SET    nom = 'foo',
       score = 1,
       rang = 0
WHERE  id = (SELECT id
             ORDER  BY score DESC
             LIMIT  1);
```

I want to update only the row with the highest score (i.e. 94) but when I execute the request, every line of the table are taking these values ([demo](http://rextester.com/JUCVOV55702)).

```
+----+-----+-------+------+
| id | nom | score | rang |
+----+-----+-------+------+
|  1 | foo |     1 |    0 |
|  2 | foo |     1 |    0 |
|  3 | foo |     1 |    0 |
|  4 | foo |     1 |    0 |
+----+-----+-------+------+
```

I don't understand why ? Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order by` and `limit` in an `update` in MySQL.  So, I think you mean:

```
UPDATE scores
    SET nom = 'foo', score = 1, rang = 0
    ORDER BY score DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: That's true ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
update scores SET nom='foo', score=1, rang=0 WHERE id= (SELECT id order by score DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Think about what this statement says.  Remember that the equality checks are what limit the row set.  Every update statement implicitly means "update every row that matches the where clause".

So start by looking at the sub-query.

```
(SELECT id order by score DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Notice there is no `FROM` clause in that query?  Without a `FROM` clause, what are the `id` and `score` column names relative to?  They are relative to the outer statement.  The `order by score DESC LIMIT 1` is misleading.  They work, but they don't do much because you are sorting a single number.

With this `WHERE` clause running against each row:

```
WHERE id= (SELECT id order by score DESC LIMIT 1)
```

What are you saying is, this row matches if his `id` column equals his `id` column.  Well, for a given row, the value in a given column always equals itself.

Therefore, your overall update predicate is saying match any row whose `id` equals its `id`, which naturally, will match every single row.

I think what you mean is:

```
update scores
SET nom='foo', score=1, rang=0
WHERE id= (SELECT s.id from scores s order by s.score DESC LIMIT 1)
```

That says, find the highest `id` in the `scores` table, then update any row whose `id` equals that specific `id`.  It should match only one row.

You can also simplify the whole thing as Gordon pointed out:

```
UPDATE scores
SET nom = 'foo', score = 1, rang = 0
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Interesting that this got an upvote, because most of the queries will generate errors in MySQL.

Comment: it answers the `every line of the table are taking these values. I don't understand why?` part of the question. The penultimate query would give a `You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause` error though I imagine.